# jQuery if each statement

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a load more function via jQuery which partially works, in that it shows the read more, but it should be hidden on any elements without an LI

The second part increases the height of the UL element when load more is clicked, but this happens on every ul and not where the load more was clicked

```
$('.loadMore').hide();
$(".box-category li ul li").each(function() {
if ( $(this).has('ul').length ) {
 $(this).find('.loadMore').show();
 $(this).find('ul').css({'overflow' : 'hidden', height : '50px'});
 $('.loadMore').click(function () {
  $('.box-category li ul li ul').css('height','auto');
  $('.loadMore').hide();
  });
 }
});
```

How can I get it to open each individual UL and not every UL?

HTML Code (there are if statements in between to check if an item should be displayed)

```
<ul class="box-category">
 <li>
  <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="<?php echo $sisters['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $sisters['name']; ?></a>
       </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="loadMore">Load more</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: show your html and css part of code.

Comment: `if( ($(".box-category li ul li").has("ul").length )` extra `(` not sure if this is issue

Comment: Added my html to post

Answer (score 2):

Your code throws: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

This is because you have too many open brackets:

```
if( ($(".box-category li ul li").has("ul").length ) {
  ^ ^                                             ^
```

Simply change this to:

```
if ( $(".box-category li ul li").has("ul").length ) {
```

--

In specifying `$('.loadMore').show()`, you're calling the `.show()` method on **ALL** elements with a class of "loadMore", not just those specific to your `.box-category` element.

Assuming your `.loadMore` element is contained within your `.box-category` element, you can instead do this:

```
$('.loadMore').hide();
$(".box-category li ul li").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).has('ul').length ) {
        $(this).find('.loadMore').show();
        $(this).find('ul').css({ ... });
    }
});
```

This loops through every `.box-category li ul li` element and attempts to find the `.loadMore` element within before calling `show()`. It then applies the styling to the `ul` contained within the same `li`.

You can separate your `.loadMore` click function out into the main code.

Comment: yeah spotted that literally just after I posted it, updated my code

Comment: @GarethGillman my code should work fine here. Could you please post up a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.com) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Ah, I missed a `.` before `each`. Your JavaScript console will have alerted you to this. Try it now?

Comment: Nope, still opens every ul and not just the one.... Will add new code to first post